# How to load a subpages under the main page in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Imagine you have your html page (*main.html*) devided by 4 divs: top, right, left and bottom. On left div is menu with any buttons (links). Then you have next html file (*subpage.html*) and after clicking the button from left div in *main.html* I want top, left and bottom divs stay from *main.html* but on right div will content from *subpage.html*.

How can I do this without copy all source code **from main.html** to **subpage.html with changed right div**, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials are off-topic, and without an attempt at an implementation of this, this question is too broad to answer (there are too many solutions).

Comment: use ajax to load partials

Answer (score 1):

You can use iframe or frames. Both of which is not the cleanest solution. Apart from that you should look into eg. PHP to output the template you need for every page.